# A finer tuned universe

Tags: cosmology, standard-model, physical-constants, fine-tuning, anthropic-principle

I was reading about the idea of the fine-tuned universe and the anthropic principle. It is stated how small changes in some of the physical constants would render life as we know it impossible.

My question is to do with the opposite of this idea, i.e. which constants could be changed to make the universe more likely to harbour life? Obviously we are restricted by what we know as life but my thinking is more in the lines of how could the universe be made more stable, longer lasting or to have increase in some idea of 'order'?

Is it even possible to imagine such universes?

Comment: How much finer tuned to life could it be? Perhaps you should qualify?

Comment: You might be interested in a series of papers *Multiverse Predictions for Habitability* by MC Sandora in [special issue *the Multiverse*](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/universe/special_issues/the_multiverse).

Comment: First you need a definition in terms of basic physics of what life is.  There isn't one.  Pretty much by definition the answer is going to be "a universe like this" because the only life we have for reference is tuned to this universe's physics.

Comment: @Gert Yes I meant in terms of some propertly like 'the formation of heavier elements' or 'the dispersal of energy and matter across the universe'.

Comment: Obviously these depend upon our own understanding of how life formed and it's impossible to come up with some absolute criteria so yes perhaps the only answer is just as @StephenG pointed out.